# MongoDB Cursor hangs

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Working on a local copy of a larger project database, the mongodb cursor seems to hang for most queries. Specifically, I'm working with PyMongo, but even a simple `count()` over the collection hangs (*so the problem isn't a python problem*).

Iterating the cursor until the point it gets stuck reveals it always happens at the same point (i.e. for the same query) - after which it simply hangs. 
Trying `cursor.alive` reveals that it is indeed alive and well.

Dropping and rebuilding indices doesn't help either.

Running mongodb version 2.6.4. and PyMongo version 3.02. The db contains around 1.2M items.

Anyone experience anything of that sort? 
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I'm working with big data and in my practice there were such cases but reasons were different.

Here're reasons that can hang MongoDB cursor:

- when machine is very loaded or not enough good for big data like that
- when calling `sort()` method on properties which hasn't indices
- when each document size is too big and on requesting is not set `limit/batchSize`.

I could fix that issue by adding `batchSize` in queries like this:

```
db.players.find().batchSize(50).limt(10)
```

More info about MongoDB batch size you can find [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize)

Comment: please try to be more descriptive in your explanation